# openssl command line to verify the signature

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, openssl, digital-signature

Hi I have generated a key pair and used the private key to generate a signature.

```
openssl rsautl -sign -in helloworld.txt -inkey aa.pem -out sig
```

However I am unable to verify the signature with my public key:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in helloworld.txt -inkey aa.pub -sigfile sig
```

I know there -sigfile is deprecated. and some of the online doc from openssl.org is wrong.

Whats the command I should use to verify the sig with my public key?

Comment: your method is correct, I was missing digest part, trying to sign the whole document! Thanks for your help! I also found out some useful links I use it to do the X.509 CA thing: http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/howto.ca.html http://octaldream.com/~scottm/talks/ssl/opensslca.html

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I found two solutions to your problem.

You can use rsautl that way: (with private key: my.key and public key my-pub.pem)

```
$ openssl rsautl -sign -inkey my.key -out in.txt.rsa -in in.txt
Enter pass phrase for my.key:
$ openssl rsautl -verify -inkey my-pub.pem -in in.txt.rsa -pubin
Bonjour
```

With this method, all the document is included within the signature file and is outputted by the final command.

But in my case, my certificate says: Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption.
So I would recommend you to use the standard way of signing document in 4 steps: (This method is used for all asymmetric electronic signatures in order not to overcharge the signature file and/or CPU usage)

1. Create digest of document to sign *(sender)*
2. Sign digest with private key *(sender)*
3. Create digest of document to verify *(recipient)*
4. Verify signature with public key *(recipient)*

OpenSSL does this in two steps:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign my.key -out in.txt.sha256 in.txt 
Enter pass phrase for my.key:
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -verify my-pub.pem -signature in.txt.sha256 in.txt  
Verified OK
```

With this method, you sent the recipient two documents: the original file *plain text*, the signature file *signed digest*. Attention: the signature file does not include the whole document! Only the digest.

Comment: When using this very command line to verify the signature of a given data, I get the following error output : `Verification failure\n Error in dgst` does this mean the verification failed because of an error or because the files didn't match correctly ?

Comment: There is no real reason for signature decoding to fail, so I'd say mismatch.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the format of the signature is important ? I think the format `.sign` is not handled

Comment: You should really look at the documentation. Signature files are text files, extensions does not matter. Yes there is a format for the content of the file, but without looking at it, I can't say if it's ok. Test it first with the command I put here and a random text file, it should work, then test your own files.

Answer (score 5):

Verify using public key:

```
echo "plop" > "helloworld.txt"
openssl rsautl -sign -in helloworld.txt -inkey private.pem -out sig
openssl rsautl -verify -in sig -inkey public.pem -pubin
> plop
```

Answer (score 4):

your method is basically correct. What you miss is to tell rsautl that the inut key file file is a public key by add "-pubin".
The item "-pubin" OpenSSL rsautl document isn't accurate
"
-pubin
the input file is an RSA public key. 
"
should be
"
-pubin
the input key file is an RSA public key. 
"
Since the input file should be a signature file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the doc for [rsautl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html)

In your example, this would give :

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in sig -inkey aa.pem
```

I have copied my full history below :

```
echo "plop" > "helloworld.txt"
openssl rsautl -sign -in helloworld.txt -inkey aa.pem -out sig
openssl rsautl -verify -in sig -inkey aa.pem
> plop
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I did read the manual, But I need to use a public key to verify. not private key.

Comment: use -pubin and pass the public key as an argument to -inkey