# Difference between openSSL rsautl and dgst

Tags: openssl, digital-signature

The following command generates a signature for an input file:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign privateKey.pem -out signature1 someInputFile
```

The following commands also generates a signature for an input file:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha1 someInputFile > digest
openssl rsautl -sign -in digest -inkey privateKey.pem -out signature2
```

As far as I know, they should both create the RSA signature of a SHA1 digest of the file. But they don't generate the same signature.

As a result, the signature generated with method 2 can also not be verified by an `openssl dgst -verify` call.

Does somebody know what the difference is, and how that can be overcome?

Comment: The correct answer was provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140425/openssl-command-line-to-verify-the-signature. M'vy shows that ``rsautl -sign`` includes the encrypted contents of the input file (or digest in your case) in the output signature file. To just do raw RSA signing, use ``openssl pkeyutl`` as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380856/openssl-signature-difference-when-using-c-routines-and-openssl-dgst-rsautl-comm/10443732#10443732

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham excellent, Jonathan. Can you provide that as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simple answer is that `dgst -sign` creates a hash, ASN1 encodes it, and then signs the ASN1 encoded hash, whereas `rsautl -sign` just signs the input without hashing or ASN1 encoding. Both methods include the input data in the output, together with the signature, rather than producing only a signature as output. Here is a Bash script that shows the difference between `openssl dgst -sign` and `openssl rsautl -sign`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# @(#) Bash script demos difference between openssl rsautl and dgst signing
# Usage: $0 <name of file to sign> <private key file, without passphrase>

# 1. Make an ASN1 config file

cat >asn1.conf <<EOF
asn1 = SEQUENCE:digest_info_and_digest

[digest_info_and_digest]
dinfo = SEQUENCE:digest_info
digest = FORMAT:HEX,OCT:`openssl dgst -sha256 $1 |cut -f 2 -d ' '`

[digest_info]
algid = OID:2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
params = NULL

EOF

# If you are wondering what the "algid = OID:2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1" is, it's
# the SHA256 OID, see http://oid-info.com/get/2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1

# 2. Make a DER encoded ASN1 structure that contains the hash and
# the hash type
openssl asn1parse -i -genconf asn1.conf -out $1.dgst.asn1

# 3. Make a signature file that contains both the ASN1 structure and
# its signature
openssl rsautl -sign -in $1.dgst.asn1 -inkey $2 -out $1.sig.rsa

# 4. Verify the signature that we just made and ouput the ASN structure
openssl rsautl -verify -in $1.sig.rsa -inkey $2 -out $1.dgst.asn1_v

# 5. Verify that the output from the signature matches the original
# ASN1 structure
diff $1.dgst.asn1 $1.dgst.asn1_v

# 6. Do the equivalent of steps 1-5 above in one "dgst" command
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign $2 -out $1.sig.rsa_dgst $1

# 7. Verify that the signature file produced from the rsautl and the dgst
# are identical
diff $1.sig.rsa $1.sig.rsa_dgst
```

See my comment above to the OP for the credits.

Comment: This is nice! But the asn1-files created in steps 2 and 3 contain the sha256-digest of the file (`$0`), *not* an entire signature.

Comment: `pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:$hash` (available since 1.0.0 in 2010) is much simpler. Or look at the prefix constants in PKCS1=rfc2437/rfc3447/rfc8017.

Answer (score 3):

The first one [creates a signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-8.2). The second one [encrypts the hash](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2). They are not doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, @ansur, for your answer. But as I understand it, creating a digital signature is the same as encrypting the hash with a private key. In the first method, I specify SHA1 hashing to be used, and the private key to sign the hash with, the same as the second method. Do you know what the first method does differently from the second?