# ECDSA sign using OpenSSL without ASN1 encoding the hash

Tags: cryptography, openssl, digital-signature

Im doing ECDSA signatures using `dgst` command with OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.pem -out my_signature data_file
```

which works just fine. However I read in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951559/difference-between-openssl-rsautl-and-dgst) that it first SHA256 hashes the data_file, and *ASN.1 encodes* the hash before signing it.

I would like to create the SHA256 hash of the data and make ECDSA sign just the raw bytes of this hash. (As this is the ECDSA signature, I cannot use `rsautl` as in the mentioned SO answer.)

How do I achieve this using OpenSSL?

Comment: **Your premise is wrong.** #9951559 is _only_ about RSA, and only OpenSSL's default 'padding' which is RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5, where the standard calls for ASN.1-encoding the hash. The standards for RSA-PSS, DSA, and ECDSA do not include ASN.1-encoding the hash and `dgst -sign` for those cases does not do so. However, DSA and ECDSA _signatures_ are ASN.1 encoded as noted in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `openssl pkeyutl` which is a replacement for `openssl rsautl` 
that supports ECDSA.

Suppose you want to hash and sign a 'data.txt' file with openssl. At first you 
need to hash the file:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -out data.sha256 data.txt
```

after you can sign it:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey private.pem -in data.sha256 -out data.sig
```

However the signature is still in ASN.1 format. To receive r and s values 
of signature use `openssl asn1parse`:

```
openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in data.sig
```