# Does OpenSSL -sign for ECDSA apply ASN1 encoding to the hash before signing?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, digital-signature, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

This SO question [ECDSA sign using OpenSSL without ASN1 encoding the hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421399/ecdsa-sign-using-openssl-without-asn1-encoding-the-hash) states the OpenSSL perfoms ASN1 encoding to the hash before signing it.

In other words it states that OpenSSL performs the following steps when for an Elliptic curve key -sign is called:
a.  Calculate H = Hash(M)
b.  Encode H into ASN1 standard- H’
c.  Sign H’

And thus to avoid applyting step b it's neccessary to first calculate the digest, and then sign the digest using raw signing - pkeyutl for elliptic curver keys

However when I run BOTH -sign and -dgst+ -pkeyutl I am able to verify the signature using -verify in both cases. This implies that ASN1 encoding is NOT being applied to the hash.

Can anyone throw some light on this topic? I was not able to find documentation in the OpenSSL documentation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: This is a question impacts how to program with Python using OpenSSL and PyOpenSSL, since I don't know what action the OpenSSL API performs. It's a follow up to a different question that appeared here  "ECDSA sign using OpenSSL without ASN1 encoding the hash". I can try to post on CryptoStackExchange instead though.

Comment: #25421399 was wrong; it misinterpreted #9951599.

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL applies ASN.1 DER encoding to the output of the signature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm

> 1. Calculate `e = HASH (m)`, where HASH is a cryptographic hash function, such as SHA-2.
> 2. Let `z` be the `Ln` leftmost bits of `e` , where `Ln` is the bit length of the group order `n`.
> 3. Select a cryptographically secure random integer `k` from `[1, n - 1]`.
> 4. Calculate the curve point `(x1, y1) = k x G`.
> 5. Calculate `r = x1 mod n`. If `r = 0`, go back to step 3.
> 6. Calculate `s = (k − 1) x (z + r * dA) mod n`. If `s = 0`, go back to step 3.
> 7. The signature is the pair `(r, s)`.

The problem is that the ECDSA algorithm ends with math, not with bytes.  Two different conventions have arisen for how to turn that pair of numbers into bytes.  (Contrast with RSA, whose last step says how to turn the mathematical value back into bytes and declares that byte sequence to be the signature).

Let's assert that we produced a signature (against secp256r1) with `r = 67432751043532511959904657272700966685609390316545000351652696368910338707793` and `s = 15800012655857962601029927988066555130680701005265153794330961`.

#### ASN.1 DER

Used by X.509/PKIX and OpenSSL.  First declared (that I can find, anyways) by [RFC 3279, sec 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.2.3):

> When signing, the ECDSA algorithm generates two values.  These values
> are commonly referred to as r and s.  To easily transfer these two
> values as one signature, they MUST be ASN.1 encoded using the
> following ASN.1 structure:

```
Ecdsa-Sig-Value  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     r     INTEGER,
     s     INTEGER  }
```

DER works best if we build it inside out, so let's encode `r`.

`r` is an integer, `67432751043532511959904657272700966685609390316545000351652696368910338707793` in decimal, or `951595A548D156D51655159654ADA548D156D5165195159654ADA54D156D5151` hex.  [ITU-T-REC-X.690-201508](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/recommendation.asp?lang=en&parent=T-REC-X.690-201508-I) says that the integer gets encoded as a signed big endian value.  Since the most significant byte (`0x95`) has the high bit set this is a negative number, so we need to insert an extra `0x00` to keep the number positive. So `r` takes 32+1 = 33 bytes:

```
02 21 (INTEGER, 33 bytes)
   00 (padding byte)
   95 15 95 A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48
   D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
```

`s` has decimal value `15800012655857962601029927988066555130680701005265153794330961`, or hexadecimal value `9D51655159654ADA548D156D5165195159654ADA54D156D5151`. While it starts with hex 9 it's actually `0x09`, so no padding byte is required. `s` only takes 27 bytes of content, because it's so small compared to `r`.

```
02 1A (INTEGER, 26 bytes)
   09 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 51 95
   15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
```

And now we can calculate the size of the containing SEQUENCE to be 63 bytes:

```
30 3F (CONSTRUCTED SEQUENCE, 64 bytes)
   02 21 (INTEGER, 33 bytes)
      00 (padding byte)
      95 15 95 A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48
      D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
   02 1A (INTEGER, 26 bytes)
      09 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 51 95
      15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
```

Or, linearized:

```
30 3F 02 21 00 95 15 95 A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 55 15 
96 54 AD A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 
4D 15 6D 51 51 02 1A 09 51 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD 
A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 
51 51
```

### IEEE P1363

Used by Windows.

In this format `r` and `s` are taken to be big integers of the same byte size as `n`, then concatenated.  Since `r` uses all 32 bytes it's good to go.  `s` only uses 26 bytes, so it needs 6 leading `0x00` bytes.

```
// r
95 15 95 A5 48 D1 56 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48
D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
// s
00 00 00 00 00 00 09 D5 16 55 15 96 54 AD A5 48
D1 56 D5 16 51 95 15 96 54 AD A5 4D 15 6D 51 51
```

### Conclusion

So, OpenSSL applies an ASN.1 encoding to *the signature*, not *the hash*.  The ASN.1 encoding is "more common" (in that it's what's used in ECC certificates). The Windows/IEEE way is easier.  The ASN.1 way usually ends up about 6 bytes larger (or 7 bytes larger on average for secp521r1); but *could* (1 in 2^32 chance) end up the same size, or (1 in 2^40 chance) smaller.

Also, if you ever find yourself on a committee designing a new signature scheme, remember to add the step declaring the wire representation.

Comment: Actually there is one more way to encode `r` and `s`, used by SSH2 and defined in  [RFC5656](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5656#section-3.1.2). For that case, `r` and `s` are fixed length, zero padded, prefixed by size in UInt32BE