# How to distinguish ASN.1 from P1363 encoding in OpenSSL ECDSA signature

Tags: openssl, asn.1, ecdsa

The way ECDSA signatures encode the r and s values is not well-defined: While e.g. OpenSSL exclusively uses a DER encoded ASN.1 SEQUENCE, Windows uses IEEE P1363 encoding (see [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946906/8791109) for details).

In order to enable ECDSA signature verification with OpenSSL I patched ossl_ecdsa_verify(..) in ec/ecdsa_assl.c (in OpenSSL 3 that is; in 1.0.2 it's ECDSA_verify(..) in ecdsa/ecs_vrf.c). (See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823284/transform-p1363-encoded-signature-into-ecdsa-sig-using-openssl) for a related question on debugging the patch.)

Stock code does this:

```
/*-
 * returns
 *      1: correct signature
 *      0: incorrect signature
 *     -1: error
 */
int ossl_ecdsa_verify(int type, const unsigned char *dgst, int dgst_len,
                      const unsigned char *sigbuf, int sig_len, EC_KEY *eckey)
{
    ECDSA_SIG *s;
    const unsigned char *p = sigbuf;
    unsigned char *der = NULL;
    int derlen = -1;
    int ret = -1;

    s = ECDSA_SIG_new();
    if (s == NULL)
        return ret;
    if (d2i_ECDSA_SIG(&s, &p, sig_len) == NULL)
        goto err;
    /* Ensure signature uses DER and doesn't have trailing garbage */
    derlen = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(s, &der);
    if (derlen != sig_len || memcmp(sigbuf, der, derlen) != 0)
        goto err;
    ret = ECDSA_do_verify(dgst, dgst_len, s, eckey);
 err:
    OPENSSL_free(der);
    ECDSA_SIG_free(s);
    return ret;
}
```

My patch does this:

```
int ossl_ecdsa_verify(int type, const unsigned char *dgst, int dgst_len,
                      const unsigned char *sigbuf, int sig_len, EC_KEY *eckey)
{
    ECDSA_SIG *s;
    const unsigned char *p = sigbuf;
    unsigned char *der = NULL;
    int derlen = -1;
    int ret = -1;

    s = ECDSA_SIG_new();
    if (s == NULL)
        return ret;
#ifdef P1363_PATCH
    if (d2i_ECDSA_SIG(&s, &p, sig_len) == NULL) {
        /*
         * ASN.1 decoding failed, see crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c line 515ff.
         * Assume s is encoded as IEEE P1363. for a comprehensive description see
         * ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542645/does-openssl-sign-for-ecdsa-apply-asn1-encoding-to-the-hash-before-signing
         * Fill the ECDSA_SIG from the P1363.
         */
        if ((sig_len % 2) != 0)
            return (ret);
        if (s == NULL)
            s = ECDSA_SIG_new();
        if (s == NULL)
            return (ret);
        /*
         * Prepare a buffer large enough to hold either r or s part of the P1363.
         * Add 1 to the size to allow for padding if needed.
         * Define some variables for pointer arithmetic.
         */
        int buf_size = sig_len / 2 + 1;
        void *buf = malloc(buf_size);
        const unsigned char *sigbuf_half = sigbuf + sig_len / 2;
        const unsigned char *sigbuf_full = sigbuf + sig_len;
        /*
         * Skip possible padding of the r part of the P1363.
         * I /think/ only the s part may be padded, but it does no harm to skip them
         * for the r part, too.
         */
        const unsigned char *q = sigbuf;
        while (*q == '\0' && q < sigbuf_half)
            q++;
        int buf_len = sigbuf_half - q;
        /*
         * Prepare buf for BIGNUM creation.
         */
        memcpy(buf, q, buf_len);
        if (*(char*)buf & 0x80) {
            /* Add padding if needed to assert positive integer. */
            memmove((char*)buf + 1, buf, buf_len);
            memset(buf, '\0', 1);
            buf_len++;
        }
        /*
         * Finally create the BIGNUM and put it in the r part of the ECDSA_SIG.
         */
        s->r = BN_bin2bn((const unsigned char *)buf, buf_len, NULL);

        /*
         * Now do the same for the s part...
         */
        q = sigbuf_half;
        while (*q == '\0' && q < sigbuf_full)
            q++;
        buf_len = sigbuf_full - q;
        memcpy(buf, q, buf_len);
        if (*(char*)buf & 0x80) {
            /*Add padding if needed to assert positive integer.  */
            memmove((char*)buf + 1, buf, buf_len);
            memset(buf, '\0', 1);
            buf_len++;
        }
        s->s = BN_bin2bn((const unsigned char *)buf, buf_len, NULL);

        free(buf);
    }
    else {
        /* Ensure signature uses DER and doesn't have trailing garbage */
        derlen = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(s, &der);
        if (derlen != sig_len || memcmp(sigbuf, der, derlen))
            goto err;
    }
    ret = ECDSA_do_verify(dgst, dgst_len, s, eckey);
 err:
    if (derlen > 0) {
        OPENSSL_cleanse(der, derlen);
        OPENSSL_free(der);
    }
#else
    if (d2i_ECDSA_SIG(&s, &p, sig_len) == NULL)
        goto err;
    /* Ensure signature uses DER and doesn't have trailing garbage */
    derlen = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(s, &der);
    if (derlen != sig_len || memcmp(sigbuf, der, derlen) != 0)
        goto err;
    ret = ECDSA_do_verify(dgst, dgst_len, s, eckey);
 err:
    OPENSSL_free(der);
#endif /* P1363_PATCH */
    ECDSA_SIG_free(s);
    return ret;
}
```

This allows me to verify P1363 encoded ECDSA signatures. Garbage in sigbuf is still caught by ECDSA_do_verify(..).

However OpenSSL's provided ecdsa test fails with the patch:

```
15-test_ecdsa.t ....................
        # INFO:
        # testing ECDSA for curve secp112r1 as EC key type
        # ERROR: (int) 'EVP_DigestVerify(mctx, sig, sig_len - 1, tbs, sizeof(tbs)) == -1' failed @ ..\..\..\3rdparty\openssl-3.0.5-RIB\test\ecdsatest.c:262
        # [0] compared to [-1]
        # 442C0000:error:0800009C:elliptic curve routines:ossl_ecdsa_simple_verify_sig:bad signature:..\..\..\3rdparty\openssl-3.0.5-RIB\crypto\ec\ecdsa_ossl.c:482:
        # OPENSSL_TEST_RAND_ORDER=1666859286
        not ok 1 - iteration 1
```

and so on for every single curve. I haven't been able to fully analyse, but I assume it's due to the **negative tests** fail. This would be because garbage provided by the test now runs through my code and doesn't bypass the call to ECDSA_do_verify(..). Is that correct?

In order for the test to succeed, and as a general improvement to my code, where stock OpenSSL only distinguishes 2 cases (ASN.1 or garbage) I now need to distinguish 3 cases (ASN.1, P1363 or garbage). **Is there any way to distinguish P1363 from garbage once ASN.1 decode failed?**

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do (I think!) is to attempt to decode as DER the way OpenSSL does it *and* check that that consumed the whole octet string *and* make sure that the two `INTEGER` values are correctly encoded using the minimum number of bytes (which means they cannot have the first 9 bits be all zeros or all ones).  If so, then assume ASN.1/DER, else attempt the MSFT way.  The other thing you could do is check that the length of the octet string is or isn't 64 bytes: if it's not 64 bytes, then it cannot be encoded the MSFT way, but if it is 64 bytes it's possible that `r`'s leading bytes are such that it looks like the tag-length of `SEQUENCE` and then the tag-length of the `r` `INTEGER` (which would have to be small enough to need zero-padding in the MSFT encoding) and then `s` too would need its leading two bytes to look like the tag-length of `INTEGER` and the value too would have to need 30 bytes + two bytes of zero padding in the MSFT way.