# How to verify an EC signature created by OpenSSL with the Subtle Crypto API?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, subtlecrypto

I have a small JSON file which contains an EC signature generated by [SubtleCrypto.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign#ecdsa) ECDSA algorithm and SHA512 digest. Now I manually generate the signature, but I would like to automate it. I have a restriction to use the `nginx:alpine` base image to do that. So I have installed OpenSSL, but it turns out, [SubbtleCrypto.verify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/verify) needs the signature in IEEE P1363 format, but OpenSSL uses the ASN1 format. Is there a way to use the signature generated by `openssl` in the browser?

**Note:**

I created the EC key pair in the browser and it is working fine when the signature is generated with [SubtleCrypto.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign#ecdsa).

Then I have exported the private key in PKCS#8 format, and saved it as a PEM file to be used as an input for OpenSSL.

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
<Base64 encoded content here...>
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and use the following to generate the signature in Base64 for `{}` (data.json)

```
$ openssl dgst -sha512 -sign private.pem data.json | base64
MIGHAkEZ0YthoqLqCW1ll0MvPEYdhoz+p1zxQnLt0sl0rSvD8eI0BdAeQUqS1fUlNi8O39ClI6OI
JDZJqJ3OkTFkMyqzaAJCAT8koJnhqv2PUHla7EWV/qVIBb9LtPovQODl0+CsBQlkGO+TKkX3X57+
rpOZMqYv1tIOAz1m5ry0sOo0hGSe4c8X
```

then I used this website (the link contains the signature as well in Base64 encoded ASN1 format): [asn1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGHAkEZ0YthoqLqCW1ll0MvPEYdhoz-p1zxQnLt0sl0rSvD8eI0BdAeQUqS1fUlNi8O39ClI6OIJDZJqJ3OkTFkMyqzaAJCAT8koJnhqv2PUHla7EWV_qVIBb9LtPovQODl0-CsBQlkGO-TKkX3X57-rpOZMqYv1tIOAz1m5ry0sOo0hGSe4c8X) to get the r and s decimal values, and then followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946906):

```
r = 346169932049245619871744113024266741326899713498883047336224784039276978051811648336988371154157537871201508197563500632048282301939214838670217488915673960
s = 4279009059525041370739088323750483074176965727856497966083564113228214038964554024207556176396942898795827323835166902701178318351093672293528073206493204247

hex_val = 19D18B61A2A2EA096D6597432F3C461D868CFEA75CF14272EDD2C974AD2BC3F1E23405D01E414A92D5F525362F0EDFD0A523A388243649A89DCE913164332AB368013F24A099E1AAFD8F50795AEC4595FEA54805BF4BB4FA2F40E0E5D3E0AC05096418EF932A45F75F9EFEAE939932A62FD6D20E033D66E6BCB4B0EA3484649EE1CF17
```

and the resulting base64 signature is

```
GdGLYaKi6gltZZdDLzxGHYaM/qdc8UJy7dLJdK0rw/HiNAXQHkFKktX1JTYvDt/QpSOjiCQ2SaidzpExZDMqs2gBPySgmeGq/Y9QeVrsRZX+pUgFv0u0+i9A4OXT4KwFCWQY75MqRfdfnv6uk5kypi/W0g4DPWbmvLSw6jSEZJ7hzxc=
```

and that fails to verify in the browser.

**Edit:**

I have created an example with the calculations I have made [here](https://github.com/hodossy/sign-with-openssl-verify-with-subtle-crypto/blob/main/index.html). I generated the signature with the above openssl command with the key file given and a json file containing `{}` only.

Comment: *...Is there a way to use the signature generated by openssl in the browser?...* You need to convert the signature, either with a third-party library or by yourself. The former is more convenient with regard to implementation, but creates a dependency. So it is up to your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that to no avail. I am not sure thought what is the input of the digest algorithm or if I have correctly converted the signature.

Comment: You should post a sample ASN.1/DER encoded signature and how you converted it to P1363.

Comment: I used this website (the link contains the signature as well in Base64 encoded ASN1 format): [asn1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGIAkIAzjZXUyv5EcPyLh3R7SP7pz2Kte44X7bIucOMJ2L5JEPtS1MRfnOs5aebiajNb6kD2qna3OvcIUoxaTEHuuccHn8CQgCo8EuPy5I3KsPU2DR2Fgw7ZMrkoH7U3JMDX1hTKkPGIyvfQnioksny9CmfRnBHpQDvI3oMASHhRxUKG7yapgZJmA) to get the `r` and `s` decimal values, and then followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946906)

Comment: From this description it is not possible to verify if you are doing it correctly. Post either the code with the implementation or an example with an ASN.1/DER encoded signature and the derived P1363 signature.

Comment: I did it manually, not coded it yet, although it would have been easier at this point.... I added the example I have worked with.

Comment: You have not specified the curve, perhaps secp521r1, for which the order of the base point is 521 bits large, rounded up to full octets 528 bits = 66 bytes, which thus corresponds to the size of r and s respectively. If r is smaller, it is padded from the front with 0x00 values, the same is true for s. In your case the r value is smaller (65 bytes) and gets a leading 0x00, i.e. the P1363 signature is hex encoded 0019...6801...17.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have information about the curve, but it is a very good point. I will try with proper padding, thanks!

Comment: I have created a new key pair and implemented the whole calculation available [here](https://github.com/hodossy/sign-with-openssl-verify-with-subtle-crypto/blob/main/index.html)

Comment: I cannot successfully verify the OpenSSL signature from the link in your last comment, *even with OpenSSL*. However, the OpenSSL signatures I created can be successfully verified with the JavaScript code. This means that the JavaScript code works, and that the posted data is the problem (check signature creation and data consistency).

Comment: Thanks for verifying my code! It is embarrassing, but I still struggle to achieve a verifiable signature. I use the `echo {} | openssl -sha512 -sign private.pem | base64` command to generate the signature. What command did you use?

Comment: And I just found out the importance of the `-n` flag for echo. I managed to verify a signature generated with `echo -n {} | openssl -sha512 -sign private.pem | base64`