# How secure `openssl rsautl -sign` is comparing to `openssl dgst -sign`?

Tags: ruby, openssl, digital-signature

I was doing research about a way to generate a digital signature of a file and found that there were at least two ways: `openssl rsautl -sign` and `openssl dgst -sign`.

I understand the difference between them at an algorithm level by reading [Difference between openSSL rsautl and dgst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951559/difference-between-openssl-rsautl-and-dgst)

I am wondering if there is a difference between them at a security level . I suppose that the difference between them is the ASN1 encoding and that does not affect the strength of the security level of `openssl rsautl -sign`. But if possible, I would like to make sure it.

I am planning to implement this in Ruby. It seems to me that `openssl dgst -sign` can be implemented by using `sign` in `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` and `openssl rsautl -sign` can be implemented by using `private_encrypt` in `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA`.